# How to get extension of image from URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-native

I'm working on a react native application which fetches image from URL and saves in local device.

```
const getExtention = (filename) => {
  return /[.]/.exec(filename) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(filename) : undefined;
};
```

I'm using the above code for getting image extension for this kind of files.
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Sunflower_from_Silesia2.jpg

But there are also some image urls available without extension like below

```
https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/woman-lifts-her-arms-in-victory-mount-everest-national-park-picture-id507910624?s=612x612
```

so how can i know what extension theabove image is ? to store in device

Comment: The server should report the correct MIME type of the image. Each mime type maps to one (or more) extension. You need to have a map for all the supported mime types.

Comment: @JoachimSauer can you please provide some example?

Comment: I don't work with react, so I can't provide code, but there's [plenty of documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) on what mime types are and how they work.

Comment: The question is: why you have image urls without extension ?

Comment: @BinaryMan: URLs have no "obligation" or technical reason to contain an extension (or a file name) at all. It's perfectly fine for an URL like `http://example.com/someImage` to serve a JPEG image (and happens regularly in the wild). Theoretically even `http://image.example.com` could serve an image. This is not a mistake or a problem. It's a simple truth.

Answer (score 2):

As someone have already suggested in comments about MIME type mapping and in agreement I would say, to detect/fetch extension of remote file URLs, you can't do it without knowing it's MIME type.

```
var url = 'https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/woman-lifts-her-arms-in-victory-mount-everest-national-park-picture-id507910624?s=612x612';
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open('HEAD', url);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
    }
};
xhttp.send();
```

With above code, I was able to get its type, which is **image/jpeg**. Now, to convert MIME type to .ext, you can either create your own list to do that or use any of below packages:

- [mime-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types)
- [mime-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-db)

Answer (score 0):

As @Joachim and @CodeGeek pointed out, the url provides *no* hint for the type of the image (extension of the image), so you have to get that information from the "Content-Type".

After retrieve Content-Type, something like "image/jpeg" or "image/png", split the string using "/", and the second part of it can be used as extension of the file.